# Lining up font awesome icon with text

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Per the image below, these set on the same line, but I need the text centered with the icon, not at the bottom. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="alertBtns">
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-show="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="ppt.Swipes.length>0"></i>outstanding swipes</button>
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="showAlerts();"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="isNotRead"></i>recent denials</button>                    
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="dateAlert"></i>upcoming dates</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:middle;` on the `i` element inside of the div.

```css
div.alertBtns i{
  vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="alertBtns">
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-show="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="ppt.Swipes.length>0"></i>outstanding swipes</button>
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="showAlerts();"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="isNotRead"></i>recent denials</button>                    
    <button class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x" ng-show="dateAlert"></i>upcoming dates</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try display:inline-block; and vertical-align:middle; in your button

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the line-height of the text.